# Filter rows which has at least one of particular values

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements, any

I have a data frame like this.

```
df
    Tour    Order   Machine    Company
[1]    A        D         D          B
[2]    B        B         A          G
[3]    A        E         B          A
[4]    C        B         C          B
[5]    A        G         G          C
```

I want to get the rows where the three columns `Tour`, `Order` `Machine` contains at least one `D` `E` or `G`.

The result should be:

```
    Tour    Order   Machine    Company
[1]    A        D         D          B
[3]    A        E         B          A
[5]    A        G         G          C
```

My attempt:

```
df %>%
    filter(any(c(Tour, Order, Machine) %in% c('D', 'E', 'G')))
```

But it doesn't filter correctly(all the rows are returned). Could anybody please help me?

Comment: share df with dput() please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option:

```
df[rowSums(sapply(df[-4], '%in%', c('D', 'E', 'G'))) > 0,]
```

The resut:

```
  Tour Order Machine Company
1    A     D       D       B
3    A     E       B       A
5    A     G       G       C
```

With `dplyr` you should add `rowwise()`:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(c(Tour, Order, Machine) %in% c('D', 'E', 'G')))
```

Answer (score 11):

Another `tidyverse` approach using `filter_at`

```
df %>% filter_at(vars(-Company), any_vars(. %in% c("D", "E", "G")))
#  Tour Order Machine Company
#1    A     D       D       B
#2    A     E       B       A
#3    A     G       G       C
```

### Update for `dplyr >= 1.0`

`filter_at` and `any_vars` have been superseded by `if_any` allowing for the more succinct

```r
df %>% filter(if_any(-Company, `%in%`, c("D", "E", "G")))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ind <- apply(sapply(df1[c("Tour","Order","Machine")],`%in%`,c('D', 'E', 'G')),1,any)
df1[ind,]
#   Tour Order Machine Company
# 1    A     D       D       B
# 3    A     E       B       A
# 5    A     G       G       C
```

- `sapply` will return a matrix of Booleans containing the match for each cell.
- `apply` will check if any of them is `TRUE`, which means you want to keep the row
- We filter input

A dplyr version:

```
df1 %>%
  filter_at(c("Tour","Order","Machine"),any_vars(.%in% c('D', 'E', 'G')))
#   Tour Order Machine Company
# 1    A     D       D       B
# 2    A     E       B       A
# 3    A     G       G       C
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,text="
 Tour    Order   Machine    Company
    A        D         D          B
    B        B         A          G
    A        E         B          A
    C        B         C          B
    A        G         G          C")
```

Comment: Does not produce the desired output, as the second line as they are not filtering on company

Answer (score 1):

You can `lapply` over the columns to check for matches, then `Reduce` using `|` (or) to select if there are any matches.

```
df[Reduce('|', lapply(df[-4], '%in%', c('D', 'E', 'G'))),]
```

Answer (score 1):

using base R:

```
df1[grepl("[DEG]",do.call(paste,df1[-4])),]# YOU CAN USE "D|E|G"

  Tour Order Machine Company
1    A     D       D       B
3    A     E       B       A
5    A     G       G       C
```